# Reputation Bonus

Tags: support, user-accounts, association

When I log in into another stack exchange website, I got 100 reputation bonus. I join superuser since the website started, and that time, there is no reputation bonus.

My question, will I be able to get reputation bonus in here, or not.

PS: My reason to get reputation bonus is to vote up the answers that really helpful that I found in this site. Most of my needs already asked and answered, so I'm stuck with 1 reputation, cannot vote up, even cannot ask question in meta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You get the reputation bonus when you have more then 200 reputation on one of the SO sites. Since you created your SU account before you had 200 rep on SO, you never initially got the bonus.

However, if you un-associate and re-associate your accounts in the accounts tab under you profile, it should pick up your SO reputation and give you the bonus this time round.

Comment: +1 - Confirmed it works!

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Just tried this, and whoa... I got +100 on ServerFault from SuperUser, and then immediately afterward got +100 on SuperUser from ServerFault. Weirdness. Well, I guess I won't complain about that...