# SO user new to SU starting with 101 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

Out of curiosity - how can a user start out with a rep of 101 on SU? I'm looking at the [profile of Merlin](https://superuser.com/users/76113/merlin?tab=accounts) and even though he has no activity visible to me (no votes anyhow), he seems to have started out at rep 101. Is that due to his other accounts on SO and Apple?

Comment: If you link your accounts you get a bonus 100 rep I think you need to have 200 rep one site first though.

Comment: I see... so rep-wise it is a mistake to join the second site before you've gone above 200 on the first ;-)

Comment: No, when you get 200 at one site you can link with any other site and it will give you +100 on the others.

Comment: Put that in an answer @Kyle ;-) Though I'm pretty sure it's a dupe of something

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is too, I believe I originally got the info off of MSO. But I guess we should have it here as well, moving..

Comment: Er, voted for duplicate, but on re-reading, there is no duplicate of this question unless you check Meta.SO.

Comment: I was surprised myself not to already find an answer on meta, at least not the way I searched... now it seems obvious to not only check SU's meta but also SO's meta...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reputation Bonus](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1539/reputation-bonus)

Comment: @BloodPhilia: I thought the same, but it isn't.

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg: It's not bad to have a cross-site duplicate here as there will always be people that look here and that's fine. But indeed, for finding information that's not site-specific it would be a better place to look...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you link your accounts with a common ID like OpenID you get a bonus 100 rep, however you need to have 200 rep one site first though. This will back date as well, so if you link accounts, for example between Stack Overflow and Super user before getting 200 on either site then link with another site after getting 200 rep all your accounts will get the bonus 100 rep.

Comment: ... which I confirmed by creating a profile on Physics with the same openid :-)